# Read a slice from a json file in golang

Tags: json, go, slice

How do I read a slice from a `json` file in golang? For example, the file `data.json` looks like this:

`["a","b","c","d"]`

I have tried using `ioutil.ReadFile` to do this, but this returns a string, not a slice. How can I read my slice?
**NOTE**: You can sub the brackets `[]` for braces `{}`
I have done this using structs, but I don't want the user to have to type in this complicated json stuff

Comment: It doesn't have to be json. I just want it to work :)

Comment: Fixed it! Is it good now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("data.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print("data:  ",string(data))
    var slice []string
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &slice)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("slice: %q\n",slice)
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat data.json
["a","b","c","d"]
$ go run data.go
data:  ["a","b","c","d"]
slice: ["a" "b" "c" "d"]
$
```

Comment: You probably should mention using `json.NewDecoder` if the file is large since it'd be more efficient.